# Safari "Submit" buttons disappears on hover on screen resize

Tags: html, css

I have a contact form that is split between 2 columns. Everything is working fine on Firefox and Chrome however in Safari when my columns stack at a smaller screen size or on mobile the submit button disappears on hover.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75ecvyev/)

My HTML and CSS is:

```css
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
/* Reset CSS
 * --------------------------------------- */
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,
form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
a{
 text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 0.6em;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
fieldset,img {
    border: 0;
}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
strong{
 font-weight: bold;
}
ol,ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
caption,th {
    text-align: left;

}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#444;
}
q:before,q:after {
    content:'';
}
abbr,acronym { border: 0;
}


/* Custom CSS
 * --------------------------------------- */
 body{
   font-family: Roboto, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
   color: #F2F2F2;
  }  
  
.wrap{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 960px;
 position: relative;
}
h1{
   font-size: 4em;
            font-weight: 900;
  }

h1#h1ssl{
   font-size: 3.2em;
            font-weight: 900;
  }

h2#h2a1{
   font-family: Abril Fatface;
            font-size: 4em;
            font-weight: 900;
            color: #840000;
  }

h2#h2a2{
   font-family: Abril Fatface;
            font-size: 2em;
            font-weight: 900;
            color: #840000;
  }
 h2#h2b1{
            font-size: 2em;
            font-weight: 900;
            color: #00cccc;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            padding-bottom: 8px;
  }

p{
   font-size: 2em;
  }       
   
 p#p1c2a{
   font-size: 1em;
            color: #efefef;
  } 
}
    
.intro p{
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

div#adhoc {
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}

/*========== Contact Form ===========*/

label {
    display:block;
    letter-spacing:2px;
}

input, textarea {
    font-family: Roboto, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 width:439px;
 height:22px;
 background:#efefef;
 border:1px solid #dedede;
 padding:10px;
 margin-top:3px;
 font-size:0.9em;
 color:#3a3a3a;
       -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.select-field {
    font-family: Roboto, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 8px;
 width:459px;
    font-size:0.9em;
    margin-top:3px;
        border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background:#efefef;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.select-field:focus {
    outline: none;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;   
}


.form-style .input-field:focus,
.form-style:focus,
.form-style .textarea-field:focus,  
.form-style .select-field:focus{
    border: 1px solid #999999;
}

.form-style input[type="button"],
.form-style input[type="submit"] {
     width:127px;
    height:38px;
    background-color: #00cccc;
    color: #efefef;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    border:none;
    margin-top:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.form-style input[type="button"]:hover,
.form-style input[type="submit"]:hover {
    opacity:.9;
}
.form-style .success{
 background: #444;
 padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
 margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
 border: none;
    font-size: 3em;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #00cccc; 
}
.form-style .error {
 background: #444;
 padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
 margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
 border: none;
    font-size: 3em;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #ff6600;
}

/*========== Columns ===========*/
div.col-2a {     
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 4%;
    padding-right: 4%;
}
        
div.col-2b {
     -webkit-column-count: 2; 
    -webkit-column-width: 440px;    
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;      
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    text-align: left;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-width: 440px;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;      
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    text-align: left;
    /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
    column-width: 440px;            
    column-gap:40px;      
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    text-align: left;
}



 /*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

    /* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
 @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
        h1{
   font-size: 1em;
  }
     h1#h1ssl{
   font-size: 1.8em;
  }
     
     h2#h2a1{
            font-size: 1.1em;
  }

     h2#h2a2{
            font-size: 1em;
  }
  p{
   font-size: 1em;
  } 
      p#p1e{
   font-size: 1.5em;
  } 
       p#p1c2a{
   font-size: 1em;
  } 
        a{
    font-size: 1em;
}
input, textarea {
 width:260px;    
    }
.select-field {
 width:280px;
}
     

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 440px) {
        h1{
   font-size: 1.25em;
  }
         h1#h1ssl{
   font-size: 3.2em;
  }
     
        h2#h2a1{
            font-size: 1.5em;
  }

        h2#h2a2{
            font-size: 1em;
  }
        
  p{
   font-size: 1em;
  } 
        p#1e{
   font-size: 1.5em;
  } 
          p#p1c2a{
   font-size: 1em;
  } 
              a{
    font-size: 1em;
}
     input, textarea {
 width:439px;
    }
        .select-field {
 width:459px;
}
        
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width : 600px) {
        h1{
   font-size: 2em;
  }
        h1#h1ssl{
   font-size: 3.2em;
  }
        h2#h2a1{
            font-size: 2em;
  }

        h2#h2a2{
            font-size: 2em;
  }
  
  p{
   font-size: 1em;
  } 
          p#p1c2a{
   font-size: 1em;
  } 
              a{
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
    }
     @media only screen and (min-width : 740px) {
        h1{
   font-size: 2.5em;
  }
        h2#h2a1{
            font-size: 2.5em;
  }

        h2#h2a2{
            font-size: 2em;
  }
  
  p{
   font-size: 1.25em;
  } 
           p#p1c2a{
   font-size: 1.25em;
  } 
              a{
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 900px) {
        h1{
   font-size: 3em;
  }
        h2#h2a1{
            font-size: 3em;
  }

        h2#h2a2{
            font-size: 2em;
  }
  
  p{
   font-size: 1.5em;
  } 
          p#p1c2a{
   font-size: 1em;
  } 
              a{
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
        div.col-2a {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; 
    -webkit-column-width: 440px;    
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    -webkit-text-align: left;
    -webkit-padding-left: 4%;
    -webkit-padding-right: 4%;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-width: 440px;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-text-align: left;
    -moz-padding-left: 4%;
    -moz-padding-right: 4%;
    /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
    column-width: 440px;      
    column-gap:40px;      
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 4%;
    padding-right: 4%;
}
        
    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 1040px) {
        h1{
   font-size: 3.5em;
  }
        h2#h2a1{
            font-size: 3.5em;
  }

        h2#h2a2{
            font-size: 2em;
  }
  
  p{
   font-size: 1.75em;
  } 
          p#p1c2a{
   font-size: 1em;
  } 
              a{
    font-size: 0.6em;
}
        div.col-2a {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; 
    -webkit-column-width: 440px;    
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    -webkit-text-align: left;
    -webkit-padding-left: 4%;
    -webkit-padding-right: 4%;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-width: 440px;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-text-align: left;
    -moz-padding-left: 4%;
    -moz-padding-right: 4%;
    /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
    column-width: 440px;      
    column-gap:40px;      
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 4%;
    padding-right: 4%;
}
    }

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
        h1{
   font-size: 4em;
  }
        h2#h2a1{
            font-size: 4em;
  }

        h2#h2a2{
            font-size: 2em;
  }
  
  p{
   font-size: 2em;
  } 
          p#p1c2a{
   font-size: 1em;
  } 
              a{
    font-size: 0.6em;
}
        div.col-2a {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; 
    -webkit-column-width: 440px;    
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    -webkit-text-align: left;
    -webkit-padding-left: 4%;
    -webkit-padding-right: 4%;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-width: 440px;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-text-align: left;
    -moz-padding-left: 4%;
    -moz-padding-right: 4%;
    /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
    column-width: 440px;      
    column-gap:40px;      
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 4%;
    padding-right: 4%;
}
    }
```

```html
<div class="form-style" id="contact_form">
     <div id="contact_results"></div>
    <div class="col-2b" id="contact_body">
        <label><span>Name <span class="required">*</span></span></label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="true" class="input-field"/>
        
        <label style="margin-top:20px;"><span>Email <span class="required">*</span></span> </label>
            <input type="email" name="email" required="true" class="input-field"/>
       
        <label style="margin-top:20px;"><span>Current Website</span></label>
            <input style="margin-bottom:20px;" type="text" name="website" required="false" class="input-field"/><br>
        
            <div style="display:inline-block;"><label for="subject"><span>I Want To</span></label>
            <select name="subject" class="select-field" placeholder="Choose something">
            <option value="Holder">Choose One...</option>
            <option value="New Site">Start fresh</option>
            <option value="Site Update">Add some lipstick</option>
            <option value="Other Design">Do something else</option>
            <option value="Saying Hi!">Just say Hi!</option>
            </select>
        
        <label for="field5" style="margin-top:20px;"><span>Tell Us More:<span class="required">*</span></span></label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="textarea-field" required="true" placeholder="Share your dreams or say hello!" style="height: 108px;"></textarea>
        
        
        <label>
            <span></span><input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" />
        </label></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: notice one thing that if cursor not over button, it still hover, try with `width:100%` and see if it disappear or not.

Comment: could you give it a high z index or something/

Comment: If I set the hover width to 100% then the button takes up the whole span of the column. In 2 column layout and still disappears when in a singly column layout. If I set it to 127px to match the original button it only hovers over the actual button but still disappears when in singly column layout. Even if I add all the styling elements to the hover state it still disappears. Thanks for your suggestion. Any more would be appreciated.

Comment: If I remove the opacity on however everything stays in place this is weird lol

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone else is having this issue a solution that worked for me was instead of setting Opacity to control the button hover effect I used a background rgba value on the button and everything works fine

Comment: It 2022 and it still exist